# Questions and answers in quiz aren't in line with each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a quiz. The problem here is that the questions and anwers aren't 
in line with each other. U can see what I mean here: 
h ttps://plnkr.co/edit/TtYhbMTLj2kxKDPqOUfI?p=preview

Question 2 and 3 and the answers of them are nice in line but when you add 
a letter or 2, it is moving a bit.

Anyone know what the problem may be or what a solution is ?

Comment: It has something to do with text-align: center

Comment: If you include a link, please format it correctly so people can actually click on it. The text is only in line for Items with the same length as `text-align: center;` is applied to the individual items, not everything at once. `Answer 1..3` is always the same length, therefore it's aligned properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css to your inline css

```
.row{
   text-align:left;
   margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .quizstyle {
    padding-right: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:left;
  }
```

add this to your .quizstyle class to get the questions look nicer in view.